# selective fields for jquery form validation

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I'm actually doing a survey form creation (similar to surveymonkey). There's a column where you can choose whether this question you want it to be a compulsory field or not. And from there will have the validation for that chosen fields that you just ticked when creating the form.

So now my question is, the compulsory fields are as you like, so it's not fixed.

How do I go about writing the jquery for the validation so that it validates the chosen fields according to the compulsory requirement?

Here's a sample of my codes of what I have done so far.. It only validates one of the fields. But if the person who create the form decides to have more than one compulsory fields, it doesn't check the next one.

```
<?php
$vQuery = "SELECT * FROM scFormLayout WHERE surveyID = '$id'";
$vResult = sqlsrv_query($conn, $vQuery);

while ($value = sqlsrv_fetch_array($vResult)) {
    $vID = $value['id'];
    $qnsID = 'qns'.$vID.'[]';
    $compulsory = $value['compulsory'];
    $vQuestion = $value['question'];

if ($compulsory == 'Compulsory') {
?>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            // 1. prepare the validation rules and messages.
               var rules = {"<?php echo $qnsID; ?>": "required"}; 
               var messages = {"<?php echo $qnsID; ?>": "<?php echo $vQuestion; ?> is required"};
            // 2. Initiate the validator
               var validator= new jQueryValidatorWrapper("Form",rules, messages);
            // 3. Set the click event to do the validation
               $("#btnValidate").click(function () {
                   if (!validator.validate())
                         return;
                   });
               });

   </script>
<?php } }
sqlsrv_free_stmt($vResult); ?>
```

Comment: Because you are running document.ready multiple times and it will consider the last one only.

Comment: But if I move the php codes to after document.read it doesn't even work.. T_T any idea how do I format it so that in a way it works..? Thanks..

Comment: @ManishJangir jQuery runs all the document.ready() handlers, not just the last one.

Comment: Have you considered using the jquery-validate plugin? You can add the class `required` to the inputs that are required.

Comment: @ Barmar but it will overwrite the defined objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The better way to do it would be to add a class "required" to each question(supposed to be required) in your while loop.

Then simply use jquery.validate on your form under a separate script tag inside document.ready() function. Let me know if it helped or you need more info.

--- Edit ---
For example in your case if you're showing questions coming from database to a user in a while loop, for some questions you have a "compulsory" value set to 'Compulsory'. Now you want such question only to be validated as required by jquery. Then below is how to go about it.

```
enter code here

<?php
while($res = $results) {
  echo $res['question'].'<br/>';
  if($res['compulsory'] = 'Compulsory')
      echo '<input name = "any_name" class="required">';
  else
      echo '<input name = "any_name">';
}
?>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

$('#myForm').validate();

})
</script>
```

Hope that is enough of information.

Comment: hi... would you mind giving like some examples or a guide for me because I'm quite new to jquery.. T_T thank you!

Comment: hmmm, I understand how the codes works but because the input type of my questions is selective too, here's sample of the printing out of the questions. 
if ($input == 'Multiple choice (only one answer) [Radio Button]') {
                            ?>
                            <input type="radio" class="require" name="<?php echo 'qns' . $qID; ?>[]" value="<?php echo $arr; ?>"/><?php echo $arr; ?><br/> <?php } ?>
so do i need to use if for each of the input? or is there another way of doing it? >.<;;

Comment: You'll need to have the class "required" added to each input that is compulsory. You can chose any way to do that though.